# Dead Letter Queue and Poison Queues

Tags: wcf, msmq

I understand the difference between Dead Letter Queue and Poison Queue. I will be speaking in the context of transactions and durability.

DLQ: Client sends message. MSMQ is not able to deliver the message. Message remains in queue, waiting to be sent to the destination queue.

PQ: Message is successfully delivered. WCF service processes the message. Some error occured during the WCF operations. Message is placed in the poison queue.

(please correct me if I am wrong above)

Now, if the WCF Service encounters an error, and with the transaction scope in place (attribute), then how does it place the message in the poison queue or does this have to be developed? if it needs to be developed then how is it done?
What about processing poison messages? Is there a way to place them back in the queue for processing again? How is it determined if the message is poison? For example, an operation in WCF may encounter an error but can recover from it.

Comment: See also discussion in [Amazon SQS Dead Letter Queue: Is it really dead letter or poison?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21786951)

Answer (score 1):

An answer  from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84a0a601-1e0a-4693-b5f7-868d3eacb43a/what-is-the-difference-between-dead-letter-queue-and-poison-queue-in-msmq-?forum=wcf

> A message in the Poison Queue is a message that has exceeded the
> maximum number of delivery attempts to the application.  These poison
> messages are placed in teh Poison Message Queue.  Items in the queue
> still need to be read and handled though.
>
> The Dead Letter Queue is for messages that will not be handled at all
> and no processing will be done on them.
>
> It is common to move items from the Poison Message Queue to the Dead
> Letter Queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about [Poison Message Handling on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789028.aspx) More about the MSMQ on [MSDN - How to: Exchange Messages with WCF Endpoints and Message Queuing Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx)

"When the service reads messages from the target queue under a transaction, the service may fail to process the message for various reasons. The message is then put back into the queue to be read again. To deal with messages that fail repeatedly, a set of poison-message handling properties can be configured in the binding. There are four properties: ReceiveRetryCount, MaxRetryCycles, RetryCycleDelay, and ReceiveErrorHandling. "

Comment: I did read this but in the samples provided by MSDN, I was not able to see this behavior. infact the next time the server side service started, it wouldnt process any new or old messages in the queue. So on the server side, I added code to throw an exception. I see the message still in the queue. Next time I send a messasge from client - the server does not receive it but it is in the MSMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Only Message Queuing places messages in dead-letter queues. Applications can only read and delete messages in dead-letter queues.